# How to isolate a Phaser shader to a specific object/shape?

Tags: phaser-framework

I'm using the Phaser framework. Here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Dillybob/u3mGL/13/

Here is where the filter is getting populated:

```
background = game.add.sprite(0, 0);
background.width = 800;
background.height = 600;
filter = game.add.filter('Fire', 800, 600);
filter.alpha = 0.0;
background.filters = [filter];
```

My line object is assigned to the variable `drawnObject`

So I assign that object to receive the filter like so:

`drawnObject.filters = [filter];`

But my line is now a red fiery square instead of being a line with a fiery background, why?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, be aware that drawnObject is actually a bitmap, which is rectangular shaped. It consists of white pixels, which build your line, and transparent pixels, which are taking the rest of bitmap space.

The filter you use is a pixel shader. Pixel shader describes instructions that GPU invokes for each pixel of a provided bitmap. In case of this shader, it creates fire effect based on some noise functions, but it doesn't take original bitmap into account. The original color of pixels is not preserved, it doesn't add to final effect in any way.

To achieve your expected result, you have to amend fragmentSrc in Fire.js, so that shader uses and mixes/blends original color into final pixel color and/or doesn't change pixel transparency.